# Running Hadoop Examples Jar

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, bigdata

Please help. I searched online and couldn't find anything. Most of the similar questions are unanswered or unhelpful.

Hi I am trying to run Hadoop Examples of Pi. My setup is all done and successful. I ran bim/hadoop dfs -ls and I get no error.

But this:

```
Sanjanas-MacBook-Pro:hadoop sanjanaagarwal$ /usr/local/Hadoop/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-examples-*.jar pi 10 100
Number of Maps  = 10
Samples per Map = 100
13/11/21 20:57:47 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/sanjanaagarwal/PiEstimator_TMP_3_141592654/in/part0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1435)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1433)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:226)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2400(DFSClient.java:2792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2987)

13/11/21 20:57:47 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block null bad datanode[0] nodes == null
13/11/21 20:57:47 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/sanjanaagarwal/PiEstimator_TMP_3_141592654/in/part0" - Aborting...
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/sanjanaagarwal/PiEstimator_TMP_3_141592654/in/part0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1435)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1433)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:226)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2400(DFSClient.java:2792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2987)
13/11/21 20:57:47 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Exception closing file /user/sanjanaagarwal/PiEstimator_TMP_3_141592654/in/part0 : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/sanjanaagarwal/PiEstimator_TMP_3_141592654/in/part0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1435)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1433)

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/sanjanaagarwal/PiEstimator_TMP_3_141592654/in/part0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1435)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1433)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:226)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2400(DFSClient.java:2792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2987)
```

My hadoop-env.sh is all set. Still don't know whats the problem here.. Please mention the command if there's something to check since I am pretty new with linux. Thanks

Comment: Can you paste into your question the output of running `hadoop fsck /`

Comment: @HenryShen As I mentioned in the question I already did a lot of online search and nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't solve the error so found a workaround where I got a VM from cloud era on virtualBox and ran cloudera on it.

Answer (score 2):

I think DataNode of your cluster is not running. Check using jps command.

Comment: you are right. I already did that. but couldn't figure out why is it not running

Comment: Just delete the dfs folder in DataNode and start cluster again. If still not running then there may be problem in your configuration file. check entry in /etc/hosts file and in other files.

Comment: Tried that. Finally got a VM from cloudera and ran on ubuntu

Comment: I had this problem and observed in my datanode logs that the port it was attempting to bind to was in use. The datanode would then silently fail to launch. I use a shared Linux system on which the whole class is doing a Hadoop project. It didn't surprise me therefore that the default port was in use.  Changing `dfs.datanode.address` in `./conf/hdfs-site.xml` to another port did the trick.